# Looking for query to find where two members posted in same thread

Tags: mysql, forum

I'm looking for a MySQL query to find where two users have posted in the same thread. Here's an example where user_id 1 and user_id 31 have both posted in thread_id 10.

[image: example]

So far I have created this query but it does not retrieve any results. The result should be thread_id 10.

```
SELECT thread_id
FROM post
WHERE user_id='1'
AND user_id='31'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your query is that no single row can have both users.

You can move the logic to a `having` clause (with a `group by`) to do what you want:

```
SELECT thread_id
FROM post
group by thread_id
having max(user_id = '1') > 0 and
       max(user_id ='31') > 0;
```

Comment: +1 -- nice answer.  I prefer `Mysqls` use of calculations over `case` as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT p1.thread_id
FROM post p1 JOIN post p2 ON p1.thread_id=p2.thread_id
WHERE p1.user_id='1' AND p2.user_id='31'
GROUP BY p1.thread_id
```

or

```
SELECT p1.thread_id
FROM post p1
WHERE p1.user_id='1' 
      AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM post p2 WHERE p2.thread_id=p1.thread_id AND p2.user_id='31')
GROUP BY p1.thread_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `31` and `1` where just an **example**, and you want to find **all** the thread's id who post
twice or more:

```
SELECT thread_id
FROM post  
GROUP BY thread_id
HAVING COUNT(thread_id) > 1;
```